# How we can sort JSON array in java using nested json values

Tags: java, json

I am facing some problem in sort jsonarray.

Here is my input json array

```
[ { "search":{ "mode":"match" }, "resource":{ "prescriber":{}, "identifier":[], "medicationReference":{}, "dosageInstruction":[ { "route":{}, "method":{}, "timing":{ "repeat":{ "period":1, "periodUnits":"d", "boundsPeriod":{ "start":"11/15/2016", "end":"11/23/2016" }, "frequency":1 } }, "doseQuantity":{ "unit":"mg", "code":"mg", "system":"dasdsadasd", "value":10 }, "asNeededBoolean":false, "text":"Take 10 mg by mouth nightly." } ], "dispenseRequest":{ "validityPeriod":{ "start":"11/15/2016", "end":"11/23/2016" } }, "patient":{ "reference":"asdasdsada", "display":"Jason Argonaut" }, "id":"T5YI1tCzs--JEvCICFbx8zgB", "dateWritten":"11/13/2016", "resourceType":"MedicationOrder", "status":"active" }, "fullUrl":"asdsadasa", "link":[ { "url":"dassad", "relation":"self" } ] }, { "search":{ "mode":"match" }, "resource":{ "prescriber":{ "reference":"dsfsd", "display":"Physician Cdr Inpatient, MD" }, "identifier":[ { "system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.0.1.7.2.798268", "use":"usual", "value":"971103" }, { "system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.0.1.7.3.798268.801", "use":"usual", "value":"971103:2802249019" } ], "medicationReference":{ "reference":"dfsdf", "display":"amphetamine-dextroamphetamine XR (ADDERALL XR) 15 MG 24 hr capsule" }, "dosageInstruction":[ { "route":{ "coding":[ { "system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.0.1.7.4.698288.330", "code":"15", "display":"Oral" } ], "text":"Oral" }, "method":{ "coding":[ { "system":"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.0.1.7.4.798268.8600", "code":"11", "display":"Take" } ], "text":"Take" }, "timing":{ "repeat":{ "period":1, "periodUnits":"d", "boundsPeriod":{ "start":"11/07/2015", "end":"12/07/2015" }, "frequency":1 } }, "doseQuantity":{ "unit":"capsule", "value":1 }, "asNeededBoolean":false, "text":"Take 1 capsule (15 mg total) by mouth every morning. Max Daily Amount: 15 mg" } ], "dispenseRequest":{ "validityPeriod":{ "start":"11/07/2015", "end":"12/07/2015" }, "quantity":{ "unit":"capsule", "value":30 }, "numberOfRepeatsAllowed":0, "expectedSupplyDuration":{ "unit":"days", "code":"d", "system":"urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.8", "value":30 } }, "patient":{ "reference":"https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Patient/Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB", "display":"Jason Argonaut" }, "id":"TsmsDHh.ouMCg8QqhDaAMSAB", "dateWritten":"11/07/2015", "resourceType":"MedicationOrder", "status":"active" }, "fullUrl":"https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/MedicationOrder/TsmsDHh.ouMCg8QqhDaAMSAB", "link":[ { "url":"https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/MedicationOrder/TsmsDHh.ouMCg8QqhDaAMSAB", "relation":"self" } ] } ]
```

I want to sort this array in decending sort order using the nested key

resource  -->  dosageInstruction --> timing --> repeat --> boundsPeriod --> start

How can achieve this?

Comment: JSONArray have direct mapping to Java array so you can just put it into an array and then sorting it using, maybe, a Comparator or something like this.

Comment: Are you using ```gson``` or ```org.json```?

Comment: No I am not using something like this

Comment: You'll have to use either of these to handle JSON.